# Excluding Sql Server Computed Column from being Sync

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework, calculated-columns

I have been working on a project where I have a table with a computed column. When I start sync, it says:

```
The column "TotalAmount" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator
```

I want to exclude this column from being sync.

I am using C# and Sql Server 2008 R2.

Table Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblFeeDetails](
    [RecordId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SessionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CourseId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FormNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CourseFee] [money] NOT NULL,
    [OtherCharges] [money] NOT NULL,
    [LateFee] [money] NOT NULL,
    [TotalAmount]  AS (([CourseFee]+[OtherCharges])+[LateFee]) PERSISTED,
    [Status] [bit] NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: can you give us the table or view definition ?

Comment: Is there any one at stackoverflow who can answer this question???

Answer (score 0):

You are using [SqlSyncAdapterBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.synchronization.data.server.sqlsyncadapterbuilder(v=sql.110).aspx), correct?  Using that, you can specify which columns to track.

Comment: No @Greg, I am using SqlSyncScopeProvisioning, DbSyncScopeDescription and SyncOrchestrator to sync my databases. Everything happens fine except tables having computed columns.

Comment: @SarbjitSingh You should put this information in the title or description of your question. You will attract more answers if your question is more specific. Give people lots of technical details, and they will feel more tempted to help you. (just trying to help)

Answer (score 0):

am assuming you're using GetDescriptionForTable to retrieve the schema.

you can either, remove the column from the table description Columns collection or you can manually specify which columns you want included in the GetDescriptionForTable...

e.g.,

// Definition for CustomerContact, including the list of columns to include.
Collection columnsToInclude = new Collection();

columnsToInclude.Add("CustomerId");

columnsToInclude.Add("PhoneType");

DbSyncTableDescription customerContactDescription =
    SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Sales.CustomerContact", columnsToInclude, serverConn);

Comment: have you deprovisioned and re-provisioned the scope?

Comment: I used your mentioned way but it does not include that particular column while sync-ing. Means it is not available in synced source.

Comment: @SarbjitSingh If you tried this, then copy the exact C# code that you used to try this, and put it in your question. (e.g. That way we can see which exact columns you have used) Showing what and how you have tried it, will make it easier for people to help you.